# Adding shader effects if material is not controlled by the principled BSDF?

Tags: shader-nodes

[image]

I apologize if this is not enough information, I will add more if necessary.
This is an object (hinted in the picture) imported from DAZ Studio and I'd like to create a wet effect to this object. But controlling any of principled BSDF node does not make any changes.
I'm guessing I have to add something in between "Dicktator Shell" node and "Material Output" but I'm not sure what to. It seems like none of the tutorial videos out there helped me out to solve this issue.

Cheers.

Comment: I would rather examine what this "Dicktator Shell" and the "DAZ Dual Lobe" node groups are doing on the inside. They both have shader outputs (green), meaning they only pass the complete shader information to the next node. You don't have separate color (yellow), float (grey) or vector (purple) outputs to manipulate certain aspects of the shader. So the question would be, what happens inside the group so that changing the _Principled BSDF_ doesn't seem to have any effect? And if it really doesn't, what use has it to plug it in there anyway?

Comment: However, at least the "DAZ Dual Lobe" has a few float inputs, for example _Roughness_. Maybe changing values there might help in creating a wet effect. But there the mix factor _Fac_ is set to 0.5, so I guess it uses half the values of the _Principled BSDF_ settings and half its own. Then I would should either change the value to 0 or 1 or change the roughness on both, the _Principled BSDF_ and the _"DAZ Dual Lobe" nodes. Therefore I'm voting to close this question unless you provide more details, for example tab into the node groups to show us what is going on in there.

Comment: Changing anything before the dicktator shell node doesn't have any effect. Not even the DAZ Dual Lobe. The dicktator shell and the dicktator UVs v2 acts like its own texture. (I'm not sure if I'm explaining this right). I'd like to show you the node group but I'm sorry, where do you find the node group tab? There's not a node group tab on the right vertical tabs.

Comment: What I meant was you have to press `Tab` with a node group selected. It's like going into _Edit Mode_ on an object. Then you can see what's hidden inside the group. But if changing anything before it doesn't have any effect, why are the nodes even there? Does it change something if you delete them?

Comment: Oh my gosh, didn't even know there were more nodes inside a node. https://imgur.com/a/a4TQ8v6 < This is what it looks like inside the Dicktator Shell node. But changing the principled BSDF from here works! 
But if you could still shed me some light on how to make a wet effect from here, I'd be grateful.

Comment: How to make a wet effect is a different task then just figuring out why your changes had no effect. First of all, there is so much going on inside and there's another "DAZ Dual Lobe" inside additionally to the one outside where I have no idea what it does. Then what exactly do you want as "wet effect"? How you you want to spread wetness on whatever your object is? Is it supposed to be cloth, concrete, glass? There are different kinds of "wet effect" and there are many tutorials out there for different looks.

Comment: I did take a look at multiple tutorials regarding wet effects and they all start from scratch so it confused me since I'm having to insert them in between pre made nodes, not to mention all the ones I tried had no effect hence the original topic of this question. But now I'm starting to get somewhere thanks to you over the node group discovery. The wet effect I want it is on the human skin. The shell node name gives it off. Here's the DAZ Dual Lobe node group here https://imgur.com/a/a4TQ8v6. So I guess I'll start messing with the shader nodes inside the Dicktator Shell node group...

Comment: What happens if you set the 'Influence' to 0? And then vary it?

Comment: The dicktator shell node has its own texture and a UV map so setting it to 0 gets rid of the texture. But yes the nodes before it work if I do do that.